# Gradle Build error after updating Android Studio RC 2 - android-sdk-linux' does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

My Application is not building after updating the android studio RC 2.2. Below are the exception details.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':TestClient'.
  The SDK directory 'C:\Bijesh\TestClient\export
  \home\mobilebuild\AndroidApps\android-sdk-linux' does not exist.

Comment: Open `File`, choose `Project Structure`, then in `SDK Location` search for Android SDK using `...` buttton and click `OK`

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: I added it as answer. Please, mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `File`, choose `Project Structure...`, then in `SDK Location` search for `Android SDK` using ... buttton and click `OK`